# laptop keyboard locks up after closing lid

Tags: keyboard, laptop, freeze, lock

I have a Dell Latitude 5500 and a Dell Latitude 7550. The 5500 has Debian 10 and KDE, and the 7550 has Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE. In both laptops, if I close the lid, when I open it later the built-in laptop keyboard is completely locked-up and I can't type anything. The trackpad still works though and I am able to click on "switch user". When I do this and get prompted to login again, the laptop keyboard starts working again on both laptops.

I'm not sure if this is an issue, but I have an external 10-port USB hub plugged into the laptops. I have an external keyboard and mouse plugged into them. The external keyboard also locks up, but the external mouse also works.

Why would closing the laptop lid cause the keyboard to lock up? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

dmesg output:

```
[Sat Jun 26 10:46:51 2021] usb 2-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[Sat Jun 26 10:46:51 2021] usb 2-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[Sat Jun 26 10:46:51 2021] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Sat Jun 26 10:46:52 2021] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Sat Jun 26 23:15:15 2021] usb 2-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[Sat Jun 26 23:15:15 2021] usb 2-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[Sat Jun 26 23:15:15 2021] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Sat Jun 26 23:15:16 2021] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 01:54:59 2021] usb 2-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[Mon Jun 28 01:54:59 2021] usb 2-1.4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[Mon Jun 28 01:54:59 2021] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 01:54:59 2021] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 1-1.3.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 1-1.3.4: USB disconnect, device number 9
[Mon Jun 28 07:34:57 2021] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812, bcdDevice=85.80
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub        
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0812, bcdDevice=85.81
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 2-1: Product: USB3.0 Hub        
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc. 
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] hub 2-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:06 2021] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0812, bcdDevice=85.81
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB3.0 Hub        
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc. 
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] hub 2-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] hub 2-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0a8f, bcdDevice= 0.12
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 1-1.2: Product: Logitech USB Headset
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech USB Headset
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0812, bcdDevice=85.81
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.4: Product: USB3.0 Hub        
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc. 
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] hub 2-1.4:1.0: USB hub found
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:07 2021] hub 2-1.4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] input: Logitech USB Headset Logitech USB Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.3/0003:046D:0A8F.0007/input/input34
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] hid-generic 0003:046D:0A8F.0007: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Headset Logitech USB Headset] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input3
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812, bcdDevice=85.80
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub        
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812, bcdDevice=85.80
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB2.0 Hub        
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] hub 1-1.4:1.0: USB hub found
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] hub 1-1.4:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:08 2021] usb 1-1.3.2: new low-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c00e, bcdDevice=11.10
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.2: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.2/1-1.3.2:1.0/0003:046D:C00E.0008/input/input35
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] hid-generic 0003:046D:C00E.0008: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.2/input0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.4: new low-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c31c, bcdDevice=64.02
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.4: Product: USB Keyboard
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] usb 1-1.3.4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.4/1-1.3.4:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0009/input/input36
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0009: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.4/input0
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] input: Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.4/1-1.3.4:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.000A/input/input37
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] input: Logitech USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.4/1-1.3.4:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.000A/input/input38
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:09 2021] hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.000A: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3.4/input1
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:25 2021] kscreen_backend[162047]: segfault at 10 ip 00007fdb6825df6b sp 00007ffd034223b0 error 4 in KSC_XRandR.so[7fdb68246000+1b000]
[Mon Jun 28 07:35:25 2021] Code: 73 1c e8 58 97 fe ff 49 8b 3c 24 48 8d 73 14 e8 eb 96 fe ff 49 8b 3c 24 48 8d 73 24 e8 2e 93 fe ff e8 e9 b9 fe ff 49 8b 3c 24 <0f> b7 70 10 48 89 c5 e8 d9 92 fe ff 48 89 ef e8 e1 8f fe ff 4c 89
```

**Output of grep "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" /etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Comment: The output of `'dmesg'` would be useful in this situation.

Comment: dmesg has been added.

Comment: Can you run `'grep "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" /etc/default/grub'` and paste the output please?

Comment: I have posted the output in the question above.

Comment: See below, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, so.

1. In a terminal, open `/etc/default/grub`.
2. Find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`.
3. Replace it with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="atkbd.reset i8042.reset i8042.nomux quiet splash"`.
4. Save and exit the file.
5. Run `sudo update-grub`.

If this doesn't work, follow the same process but try `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"` instead.

Comment: It looks like this worked. Thank you!!